# Extract data from map by ID

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm pretty new to Flutter and am trying to fetch data stored in a map by their ID's.
I have tried using the `map()` function but that hasn't been of any use.
The error I get says `The return type 'bool' isn't a 'MapEntry<_, _>', as required by the closure's context.`
I have even tried converting the map into a list but that didn't work either.
Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Products {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;

  Products({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.price,
    required this.imageUrl
  });
}

class ProductItems with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, Products> _items = {};

  Map<String, Products> get items {
    return {..._items};
  }

  void addItems(Products products) {
    _items.putIfAbsent(products.id, () => Products(
        id: products.id,
        title: products.title,
        description: products.description,
        price: products.price,
        imageUrl: products.imageUrl
    ));
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Map<String, Products> findById(String productId) {
    return items.map((key, value) => value.id == productId).toList(); //this is where the error is
  }
}
```

The idea is to pass the id from the below code snippet to the '/edit-view-data' screen and then call the findById method there. The expected output on the next screen should display the title on it's Appbar for e.g Red Shirt as stored in the Map and similarly all the other properties as well in other widgets.
I reckoned that the only way to do so was by filtering the map by the ID's of the Products.

```
        trailing: Container(
          width: 150,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                        '/edit-view-data',
                        arguments: id
                    );
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.blue)
              )
```

Comment: hey coolhack7 we meet again, could u maybe add ur expected output ?

Comment: Hey!!!!Yup absolutely

Comment: just confirming, ur trying to return a Product  object based on the id right  ?

Comment: Yes.That's Right

Comment: sorry it took me some time to work around the null safety

Answer (score 1):

Oka so since your trying to return a Products class just change ur findbyid function to this:

```
Products? findById(String productId) {
    return _items[productId]; //this is the fix 
  }
```

It will return a Products class and u can access the members directly, example:

```
Products? p = productItems.findById("123")!;  
print(p.title);
```

Comment: if i've understood it wrong let me know and i'll update the answer

Comment: Works just fine. Thank you once again. Although, is there not any way to iterate through the map and filter it by the ID's of the data stored like it does in Lists?

Comment: im sorry but i didn't understand what u meant by iterate through the map and filter by id, is it like u want to go though all the Map elements and then return the one where id is the given id?